# Show these unions are equal

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $A_1, A_2, ... $ be a sequence of subsets of $X$. Let $B_1 = A_1$ and define: \begin{equation}
B_n = A_n \backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i
\end{equation}
Show that $B_1, B_2, ...$ are pairwise disjoint (already did this, thanks to the latest post), and that 
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i 
\end{equation}
And also show that: 
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i 
\end{equation}
I showed the first part in a way, which I don't find too 'aesthetic', here's how:
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_i \backslash \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} A_j) 
= A_1 \cup (A_2 \backslash A_1) \cup (A_3 \backslash (A_2 \cup A_1)) \cup ... \cup (A_n \backslash (A_{n-1} \cup .... \cup A_1)) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i 
\end{equation}
This is not too pretty in my opinion, but I think it's pretty clear as the subtraction and unions "cancel out". If there's a better solution, please let me know! :-)
For the second part, I have no idea what to do, as the infinite part confuses me. I feel like I could do the same, but yet again, no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite part is actually quite simple. Your proof of the finite part is fine, so I shall deal only with the former.

Suppose that $x \in \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i$. Then, $x \in B_n$ for some $n$, so that $x \in \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i$. Now, given that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i = \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$, we have that $x \in A_i$ for some $i \leq n$, hence $x \in \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$. Therefore $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i \subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$. The reverse containment follows similarly.

For the finite part, suppose that $x \in \displaystyle\bigcup_1^n B_i$. Then $x \in B_j$ for some $j$. But then $B_j \subset A_j$ since $B_j$ is $A_j$ minus some elements, which is still a subset of $A_j$. Hence, $x \in A_j$, so $x \in \displaystyle\bigcup_1^n A_i$.

For the reverse, if $x \in \displaystyle\bigcup_1^n A_i$, then $x \in A_j$ for some $j$. Let $S$ be the set of all numbers $j$ less than $n$ such that $x \in A_j$. $S$ has a least element, say $j_0$. Now, by $j_0$ being the least element in $S$, $x \in A_{j_0}$ and $x \notin A_k$ for any $k < j_0$. This means that $x \in A_{j_0} \backslash (\cup_1^{j_0-1} A_k)$, but then this is $B_{j_0}$, so that $x \in B_{j_0}$, hence $x \in \displaystyle\bigcup_1^n B_i$. This completes the other direction, and they are equal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes a lot of sense. 
I really struggle a lot recently with the difference of proofs when finite, compared to when infinite. 
I feel like you can "sometimes" just extend the finite solution and get the infinite proof as well, but other times it's "not allowed". I really fail to see when you can, and when you can't. 
In this example I felt like just saying "let n tend towards infinity, and we've shown what we wanted." Would that work? Why/why not? :-)

Comment: I just saw your edit. Does that mean "my proof" of the finite part doesnt work, or is it just a more sophisticated way to show it?

Comment: @NicolaiKofoed The infinite case here becomes the finite case. When we said that $x$ is in an infinite union, we brought it back to the finite case by saying that *the indexes are finite*,so if it is in some set in the union, then that set having finite index brought it back to the finite union case. In general, it is very difficult to say when things extend to the infinite case, that only comes with experience. With sets in general, it is not true as well (like countable intersection of open sets not being open). Your finite proof is correct, I've just improvised on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Damn, people here are smart hahaha.

Comment: @NicolaiKofoed If you post your questions in the right manner (as stated on the website i.e. with proper context, and good formatting, along with attempts made on the question), you will meet many smarter people on this forum, including some math professors and PhDs.

Answer (score 1):

A more formal proof of the finite part could look like this:

Clearly $B_i \subset A_i$ for all $i$, which implies $\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^n B_i \subset \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^n A_i$. So see the reverse inclusion, let $x \in \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^n A_i$. Then there exists a smallest index $j$ so that $x \in A_j$. But this means that $x \in A_j$ and $x \notin A_i$ for $i < j$, so $x \notin \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{j - 1} A_i$. But this means $x \in B_j \subset \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^n B_i$.